# How do I convince google to take down this page which contains people's leaked e-mails and passwords?

Tags: united-states, copyright, privacy

Out of curiousity, I googled my own e-mail to see what kind of results would show up. To my surprise, I found a website (blogger) that contained people's e-mails and leaked passwords for a service. For obvious reasons, I won't disclose the link or what service. The author of the blog also has a bunch of other shady shit that seems related to pirating.

I used this [link](https://support.google.com/legal/troubleshooter/1114905?hl=en) and followed these steps:

1. My request relates to blogger/blogspot
2. I would like to report the disclosure of private information or private nude images
3. I put my e-mail address, legal name, the url of the blog, "Other" as the type of personal information, and then translated the date to English (as the blog is not in English)

I sent this request a few weeks ago. Page is still up. Received no e-mail from google.

The remove content form seems woefully underwhelming and I suspect they ignored my request because I chose the wrong option. However, the form doesn't allow me to report it for copyright infringement if I say I'm not the copyright owner. "We are sorry, but we are unable to process your request at this time."

N.B: This is not related to Ashley Madison.

Answer (score 2):

[This page](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/2744324?hl=en) on Google's removal policies states that the information they really make an effort to remove are:

- Government IDs of any kind
- Financial information (routing numbers, credit/debit card numbers, etc.)
- Nude or otherwise personally explicit photos
- Other info that can be used for fraud (such as your signature)

It also states information they usually don't take action to remove:

- Date of birth
- Addresses
- Telephone numbers

By looking at this, I'm assuming email addresses fall into the list of info they *won't* take action on. Now, your email and password may be used to login to something critical such as a bank account. In that case, contact Google again and tell them that's what your credentials are for (no need to tell them exactly what bank or anything obviously). Just let them know the credentials on that website can be used to directly harm you and others financially or in another very personal way, assuming that's the case here.

Comment: It looks to me like it wouldn't cover passwords. I may be wrong though.

Comment: @Terry I don't think it covers passwords either, but just like the email situation I explained, it probably covers passwords if they're used for something critical.

Comment: @Terry it looks to me like the combination of an e-mail address and password most definitely "can be used for fraud."

Answer (score 0):

I would write to the blogger or the host (e.g. Blogspot) and ask that your sensitive information be removed from this blog.  I would certainly contact the host of the blog and relay the same information.  I think it goes without saying that your information has been harvested and I would change all passwords (enable two-factor authentication as well).  Thorough research on security topics is advisable and wouldn't hurt to monitor your credit in case someone has already made use of your email information.  Good luck.