# Is there a cause of action if a contest sponsor leaked my personal information?

Tags: canada, privacy, civil-law, class-action

I entered into a free contest in Canada but I did not win. But when I searched for my own email address, I found a public Google docs that contains the address, date of birth, email, name, and phone number of around 79,000 entrants. Clearly this is wrong and unreasonable - no organization should be negligent like this.

Thus what can I do? How do I tell all these other people of this breach of privacy?
 I have taken a screenshot of this Google doc.

Comment: Can you review the terms of the contest?  You may have given them permission to use that information in that way.

Comment: Also, does [this Q&A](http://law.stackexchange.com/questions/1951/how-do-i-convince-google-to-take-down-this-page-which-contains-peoples-leaked-e) answer your question?

Comment: Phone the office of the Privacy Commissioner of Canada. They're called public servants for a reason, make them do their job and serve you.

Answer (score 1):

In Australia, email addresses, like street addresses are not personal information and are not protected by the Privacy Act (which doesn't cover all businesses in any event)

Comment: Would the date of birth in conjunction with name and physical address change that though? I know some companies use that as verification when you need a password reset.